# Can't retreive environment variable in python

Tags: python, environment-variables

#### Problem

After I do

```
export key=value
```

or

```
echo "export key=value" >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

I can retrieve it in terminal using `echo $key`

But when I'm try to retrieve `key` in Python using `os.environ['key']`,

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["key"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 673, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'key'
```

There's always an error.

#### My Questions

1. Where does `export key=value` store variables? It doesn't store it in `~/.zshrc` because I can't see it when I look inside `.zshrc`
2. Where does Python inquiry when it processes `os.environ['key']`?

Comment: Did you restart terminal running Python before doing this?

Comment: but why do i have to restart terminal though? I thought restarting python is enough

Comment: When you set up an environment variable, the change is made in the current shell session. However, child processes of the current shell (such as new terminal windows or programs launched from the terminal) do not automatically inherit the environment variables from the parent shell.

So upon restarting, ensures that any new shell sessions or programs launched from the terminal have access to the updated environment variable.

Comment: So which file contains the environment variables?

Comment: It's stored in memory.

Comment: The Unix process model controls this. Exported environment variables  of a process are visible to the child processes of that process. If one of them change it, that change is only visible to the child (and its children) There is no global space which is shared between unrelated processes.